# Creating a graph in Java

Tags: java, graph

I'm building an application that implements the A* algorithm to calculate a route between two rooms. I am trying to create a graph which the algorithm can operate on and I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Here's what I've done so far:

**Vect2.java:**

```
package myalgorithm;

public class Vect2 {

    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Vect2(int x,int y ){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        }

}
```

**Node.java**

```
package myalgorithm;




public class Node {

    Node parent;
    Vect2 vector;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public double f;
    public double g;
    public double h;


    public Node( int x,int y,Node parent, double g,double h){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.parent= parent;
        this.g = g;
        this.h = h;
        this.f= this.g + this.h;

    }
}
```

**NodeGraph.java**

```
package myalgorithm;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NodeGraph {

    Node a = new Node(88,623,null,0,0);
    Node b = new Node(727,627,null,0,0);
    Node c = new Node(723,93,null,0,0);
    Node d = new Node(90,92,null,0,0);
    Node e = new Node(94,349,null,0,0);
    Node f = new Node(397,358,null,0,0);
    Node g = new Node(722,339,null,0,0);
    Node[] arr = new Node[7];


public NodeGraph init(){


    arr[0]= a;
    arr[0]= b;
    arr[0]= c;
    arr[0]= d;
    arr[0]= e;
    arr[0]= f;
    arr[0]= g;

    return this;
}
public void createMatrx(){
boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[7][];
for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) matrix[i] = new boolean[7];

int nodeA = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, a);
int nodeB = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, b);
int nodeC = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, c);
int nodeD = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, d);
int nodeE = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, e);
int nodeF = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, f);
int nodeG = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, g);

matrix[nodeA][nodeB] = true;
matrix[nodeA][nodeE] = true;
matrix[nodeB][nodeA] = true;
matrix[nodeB][nodeG] = true;
// A is connected to D
matrix[nodeC][nodeG] = true;
matrix[nodeC][nodeD] = true;
// B is connected to D
matrix[nodeD][nodeC] = true;
matrix[nodeD][nodeE] = true;
matrix[nodeE][nodeD] = true;
// C is connected to D
matrix[nodeE][nodeF] = true;
matrix[nodeE][nodeA] = true;
matrix[nodeF][nodeE] = true;
matrix[nodeE][nodeG] = true;

matrix[nodeG][nodeF] = true;
matrix[nodeE][nodeB] = true;
matrix[nodeE][nodeC] = true;

matrix[nodeD][nodeC] = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does this code work as you intend it to or are you experiencing problems with it? Have you tested the code?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg André Forsberg thank you!  I am very new to coding and I' not sure what would be the best way to test it

Comment: In general, the best - and only - way to test the code is to use and/or run the code and see if produces the output you are expecting.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg thank you! I will try and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have some problems being consisten in your coding.

1) Formatting:

In your NodeGraph class you are not consistent in your indentation. Your `createMatrx` (which has a typo and should be called `createMatrix`) you are not using any indentation.

2) Access modifiers:

In your class `Node2` you set your members private, as expected.

In your class `Node` you don't specifically set the access modifier as private for some members, and you set them explicitly publbic for others. I would expect all members to be private.

3) Naming:

Single character variable names are not very descriptive. Name your variables according to their purpose.